Reduce number of equations defining a variety
We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^5$ be a projective variety defined by the zero locus of the following two homogeneous polynomials:
\begin{equation}
X :  \begin{cases} \sum_{i=0}^5 x_i=0 \\ \sum_{i=0}^5 x_i^5 = 0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
My naive question is the following: from the first equation we obtain that $x_5 = - \sum_{i=0}^4 x_i$, and we can plug it into the second equation obtain a new equation of the form
$$ \sum_{i=0}^4 x_i^5 = \Big(\sum_{i=0}^4 x_i\Big)^5$$
So now we can describe $X$ as follows:
$$ X = \Big\{p=(p_0,\ldots,p_5)\in \mathbb{P}^5\mid \sum_{i=0}^4 p_i^5 = \Big(\sum_{i=0}^4 p_i\Big)^5, p_5=-\sum_{i=0}^4 p_i \Big\}$$
Let now $Y$ be the quintic hypersurface defined as
$$Y = \Big\{q=(q_0,\ldots,q_4)\in \mathbb{P}^4\mid \sum_{i=0}^4 q_i^5 = \Big(\sum_{i=0}^4 q_i\Big)^5\Big\}$$
Question: Are $X$ and $Y$ isomorphic?
Because my intuition would say that the linear equation $\sum_{i=0}^5 x_i=0$ is cutting a linear hyperplane $H\simeq \mathbb{P}^4$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$, therefore, $X$ cold be considered just as an hypersurface in $H$.

Dear @CraniumClamp, thanks for the reply. Do you have a rigorous proof in mind?

We can map $Y$ to $X$ by restriction of the map $\mathbb P^4\to\mathbb P^5$ given by the linear system $(q_0,\ldots,q_4,-\sum\limits_{i=0}^4q_i)$. And the map from $X$ to $Y$ is the restriction of the projection $(p_0:\ldots:p_5)\mapsto (p_0:\ldots:p_4)$. The point $(0:\ldots:0:1)$ does not lie on $X$, so the projection is well-defined.
Added: strictly speaking, the first map is not given by a linear system, because sections are linearly dependent. But still, any finite family of sections of a line bundle without common zeros gives a regular map to projective space, see Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter II, Theorem 7.1.
